# Saving a user selected file in app-specific folder

Tags: android, kotlin, file, copy, android-contentresolver

In my app, the user selects an image from the gallery (with `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()`). I can show it on the screen, but if I try to save it to my app-specific folder instead (internal or external), the app crashes.

This line:
`srcFile.copyTo(desFile)`
or this one:
`val fis = FileInputStream(srcFile)`
will close the program.
note:

- I can save a file from drawales of app to app-specific internal
  storage with my code and it not work just for user selected Image
  uri.
- I am not using "contentResolver" and tried to copy the file with
  stream (including the first line: "copyTo()").
- I expected to be able to use this uri (user selected image uri) to
  save or upload without android permissions.

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working?

**EDIT:**
With content resolver, the app also crashes. That's why I thought the problem is somewhere else. This is my code to use the contentResolver . Is there something wrong with this code?

```
fun save_image_extrnal(ctxt: Context, uri_mnbw: Uri?) {

    if (uri_mnbw != null) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val resolver = ctxt.contentResolver
            try {
                val values = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "tfh")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "frk") 
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
                }
                val uri_new = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
                val inpStream = resolver.openInputStream(uri_mnbw)
                uri_new?.let {
                    resolver.openOutputStream(it)?.use { outStream ->
                        inpStream?.copyTo(outStream)
                    }
                    values.clear()
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                    resolver.update(uri_new, values, null, null)
                }
                Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(ctxt, "$e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `ContentResolver`? That is the only way to work with a Uri.

Comment: Adding the error message would also help, if the app is crashing then you should have a Fatal error in your logcat. Also if you know the lines that are causing the crash you can use "try catch" to get more info about the error.

Comment: @ianhanniballake  I added an edit. can you take a look.

Comment: Please remove the `Toast`. Please log the exception to Logcat using `Log.e()`, then [examine the stack trace](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html) to see what the specific problem is and where it is occurring.